# Design dependencies in JUnit Test Class

Tags: java, testing, junit, dependency-injection, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Junit and testing frameworks in general, here is my question.

I have the following code:

```
public class Login extends WebsiteTestCase
{   
    @Test
    public void testChromeLogin()
    {
        setDriver( getChromeDriver() );
        login( getDriver() );
    }

    public void login( WebDriver driver )
    {
        driver.get( getBaseURL() );

        WebElement username = driver.findElement( By.name("login_username") );
        WebElement password = driver.findElement( By.name("login_password") );
        WebElement submit = driver.findElement( By.cssSelector( "form#login input" ) ); 

        username.sendKeys( getUsername() );
        password.sendKeys( getPassword() );
        submit.submit();

        assertEquals( "Website HomePage", driver.getTitle() );
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        getDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class WebsiteTestCase extends StockholmTestCase
{
    public String username = "login", password_login = "password";
    private String baseURL = "http://website.com";

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return this.username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return this.password_login;
    }

    public String getBaseURL()
    {
        return this.baseURL;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class StockholmTestCase extends TestCase
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getChromeDriver()
    {
        return new RemoteWebDriver( DesiredCapabilities.chrome() );
    }

    public WebDriver getFireFoxDriver()
    {
        return new RemoteWebDriver( DesiredCapabilities.firefox() );
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return this.driver;
    }

    public void setDriver( WebDriver driver )
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the WebsiteTestClass, I am hard-coding the current login username and password, and baseURL which works perfectly fine for my tests. But if I want to "programatically" set an environment for testing (perhaps for different programmers different login, password, different baseurl, ex: "http://Bob.dev.website.com"), then instead, I would like to be able to create an instance of WebsiteTestCase with different properties for login credentials, with a constructor.

like

```
public class Stockholm
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run( new Login( /* credentials here, settings */ ) );
    }
}
```

as opposed to

```
public class Stockholm
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run( Login.class );
    }
}
```

I understand in the above code that I am not passing an instance of Login to junit.run, so how would I design code to accomplish those things in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have property file in the project, like `webdriver-test-dev.properties` and have the login credentials & URL defined in it. You can load that property file and inject properties during the test.

Environment can be passed as command line argument like -Denv=dev and using this value the right property file can be picked considering the file name if of a predefined format like `webdriver-<env>.properties`.

Also on a related not, for a test case it is better to use one common test login instead of having each programmer use his or her own login.

Comment: If I get all of those properties wrapped up into a class instance like so:

 WebsiteSetting setting = new WebsiteSetting( getSettingsFromFile( file ) );

How would I inject that object into a Junit test?

Comment: You don't have to inject it into test. You load the properties for each test class.